# Factory pattern in Go

Tags: go, factory-pattern

I'm trying to implement a factory pattern with Go, here is the example https://play.golang.org/p/ASU0UiJ0ch

I have a interface **Pet** and a struct **Dog** so **Dog** should have the properties of **Pet**, on this case only one which is the specie, when trying to initialize the object **Dog** via the factory **NewPet**, can someone please advise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `NewPet` factory returns type `Pet`, not `*Pet` in the type assertion. (you rarely ever want a pointer to an interface)

```
return Pets[pet].(func(string) Pet)(name)
```

Your Pet constructors also need to return type `Pet` in order to satisfy the factory function signature, which you can simplify as:

```
func NewDog(name string) Pet {
    return &Dog{
        name: name,
    }
}
```

Now since all the functions have the same signature, you can define the `Pets` map with that signature to avoid the need for the type assertion

```
var Pets = map[string]func(name string) Pet
```

https://play.golang.org/p/-cz1vX-cMs